# Is a Foundation or Intermediate license from the UK recognised in the US?

Tags: united-states, license, united-kingdom

I know that a Full license is recognised in the US, but is the same true for a Foundation or Intermediate license? On the surface they look equivalent to the US Technician and General licenses, so are they treated as such?

For context, we are a UK team entering a rocketry competition in the US that has a telemetry requirement, for which we need a Technician or higher radio license, but none of us currently have a license. The time frame makes it impractical to go for a Full license, so we're hoping that getting a Foundation license here will be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US has no specific reciprocity agreement with the UK, but both countries have adopted [CEPT T/R 61-01](https://docdb.cept.org/document/925), which is what allows reciprocal operation between them. Only the UK full license is regarded as equivalent to a CEPT license; Foundation and Intermediate don't count for anything.